# Find SKU of deployed resources in Log Analytics - Azure Activity

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have configured the following Kusto query to gather info of Azure deployments in our subscription.

```
AzureActivity 
| where ResourceProviderValue startswith "Microsoft.resources" 
| where ActivitySubstatusValue contains "Created"
```

This query will display various information about new deployments across all resource providers. These are the columns that are included when running the query:

```
TenantId, SourceSystem, CallerIpAddress, CategoryValue, CorrelationId, Authorization, Authorization_d, Claims, Claims_d, Level, OperationNameValue, Properties, Properties_d, Caller, EventDataId, EventSubmissionTimestamp, HTTPRequest, OperationId, ResourceGroup, ResourceProviderValue, ActivityStatusValue, ActivitySubstatusValue, Hierarchy, TimeGenerated, SubscriptionId, OperationName, ActivityStatus, ActivitySubstatus, Category, ResourceId, ResourceProvider, Resource, Type, _ResourceId
```

however not the SKU of the deployed resource.

**I want to monitor the deployed resources in a subscription, including SKU's. Is it possible to include the SKU of deployed resources of all resource providers in a Log Analytics query from Azure Activity logs?**

Comment: Could please help us with some insights on what kind of resource provider resources(like key vault, VM's ,Storage ) you want to pull the SKU Names using the log analytics query or Could please help us with explaining some brief what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: The query gathers information about deployed resources across all resource providers. What i'm looking for is to include the type of SKU of the deployed resource. 

When a user would deploy lets say a load balancer, I want to include in the data if it's a basic or standard load balancer. Same goes for disks, compute and various other resource providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment , Below analysis are based on our observations.

The Activity log is a [platform log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/platform-logs-overview) in Azure that provides insight into subscription-level events. This includes such information as when a resource is modified or when a virtual machine is started.

> Is it possible to include the SKU of deployed resources of all
> resource providers in a Log Analytics query from Azure Activity logs?

No it is not possible,To validate this we have created a `NetworkSecurityGroup` & `DataDisk` in our subscription.

when we are trying to fetch those resources logs using `AzureActivity` table & applying a filter of  `ResourceProviderValue == "MICROSOFT.RESOURCES"`  the actual Names for those resources that are passed by the user while creating are not getting populated as shown below.

[image]

Instead of using `ResourceProviderValue == "MICROSOFT.RESOURCES"` if you use the resource specific resource provider of the resource that you are deploying  then you will be able to pull the `SKU` of that resource.

Here  Disk comes under `Microsoft.Compute` resource provider if we apply some additional filters  to the above `AzureActivity` log we can pull the sku of the particular resource.

[image]